# Python: Test that a coroutine has been closed?

Tags: python, unit-testing, async-await

I have a function like this:

```
async def my_func:
    try:
        rv = await some_other_func()
        raise Exception()
     except Exception:
        rv.close()
```

test:

```
   @pytest.mark.asyncio
   async def test_close()
        with mock.patch("module.some_other_func") as f:
            await my_func()
            f.close.assert_called_once()
```

I would like to test that my awaitable is closed in case of an exception.
Unfortunately, the coroutine never registers in the MagiCmock object.
Any ideas how to test?

Comment: Small addendum: Replacing the return_value with asynctest.CoroutineMock does not work either

Comment: Gaah,n could the person closing this question as a duplicate at least try if the "duplicate" solves this problem?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the comment. Yes, I actually did try it. I would put that into an answer, but well...

Comment: I used the `CoroMock` from that answer, and the test looked like 
      `with mock.patch("my_module.my_func.some_other_func",
                    new_callable=CoroMock) as f:
        await my_func()
        f.coro.return_value.close.assert_called_once()`